# 'Name not unique in this context' with design time CreateDataSet when fkInternalCalc fields present

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a datamodule with several `TClientDataSets` with fields and field definitions, no provider.
My recent design time changes to all of these:

- Set active=false
- Add field and fielddef for integer field `TT_APIVERSION`
- Right-click 'Create dataset'

If there are one or more fields with `FieldKind = fkInternalCalc`, I get a 'Name not unique in this context' error.
Changing them to `fkCalculated` 'solves' the issue (but I had to check my `OnCalcField` handlers to make sure they also worked for `State = dsCalcFields`)

This is code that has gone through several Delphi versions, current is Alexandria 28.0.44500.8973
We have done modifications like this before, the datasets had `Active=true` when I started, and the form contained `PersistDataPacket.Data` blobs.

Is this a (new) Delphi bug or is there something about `fkInternalCalc` fields that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all fields defined as `fkInternalCalc` from the `FieldDefs` collection before any call to `CreateDataset` (so also right-clicking 'Create dataset').

I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but `CreateDataset` tries to add `fkInternalCalc` fields to `FieldDefs` collection without checking whether it previously existed.

If you have all the `FieldDefs` and corresponding `Fields` created, you can as well delete all items from `FieldDefs` collection, field definitions will be recreated.